# UIScrollView contentInset is set to nonZero when using autolayout

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, ios9

So I have the following view hierarchy :

[image]

A full size scrollView in my viewController's view with the following constraints : [image]

These are the constraints on containerView (ignore the second last one, its a hacky semi-fix for my problem):

[image]

I have the status bar, the navigation bar and the tab bar visible.

The thing is that when I set a breakpoint to check the scrollView's contentInset, it shows 64 on top and 49 on bottom, left and right are zero.
There is no way to set contentInset in IB, I tried setting it in an IBAction to UIEdgeInsetZeio, but that didn't fix it either. This is screwing up my scrollview by adding space above and below my contentView, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the view controller extends the view under the top navigation bar so your content will blur under a translucent navigation bar.  This is controlled by `edgesForExtendLayout` which is managed in Storyboard via the Extend Edges setting.

By default, the scrollview will automatically adjust its content inset so the content appears below the top layout guide.  This is controlled by  `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` which is also managed in Storyboard.

[image]

What you did was constrain the top of your scroll view to the top layout guide instead of the top of its superview.  By doing this, you manually offset it by 64 points.  However, the scrollview is still automatically insetting its content by 64 points, which is why you're seeing additional space above and below your scroll view.

Either constrain your scrollview to its superview (so its content scrolls under the top/bottom bars), or disable the view controller from automatically adjusting the scroll view inset.